# PDFBox Page Rotation - Scaled Image Size Decreases

Tags: java, pdfbox

We are using PDFBox 2.0 version in our project. What I needed to add a QRcode image with the rotation of the page. I have taken reference from the below link ***to scale the content of the page*** after rotation. (Without this code earlier I was not able to even see the image on page)

[To scale content of the page](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatePageContent.java#L89)

But, after putting referenced code into place the actual image size showing decreased (By comparing the same image get displayed without rotation). Below are the two PDF page images with and without rotation.

[Image_Without_Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF5EB.png)

[Image_With_90_Degree_Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbqt8.png)

Herewith sharing the code to add image into page with rotation:

```
            PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(aBarcodeVO.getSourceFilePath()), "");
            int total = pdDocument.getNumberOfPages();
            
            PDPage page = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
            PDRectangle rectangle = getRotatedMediaBox(page);
            
            PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();
            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                PDPage pdPage = newDocument.importPage(pdDocument.getPage(i));
                PDRectangle pageRect = getRotatedMediaBox(pdPage);
                
                int rotation = pdPage.getRotation();
                
                PDRectangle cropBoxRect =  page.getCropBox();
                
                //Calculate margin between crop box rectangle and page rectangle.
                float[] margins = getCropBoxMargin(pageRect, cropBoxRect, rotation);
                
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
                    cropBoxRect = new PDRectangle(cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftY(), cropBoxRect.getLowerLeftX(), cropBoxRect.getHeight(),
                            cropBoxRect.getWidth());
                }
                
                //Calculate llx and lly for QR Code image.
                float rectLlx = getOffsetX(displacementVO, qrImageSize) + margins[0];
                float rectLly = getOffsetY(displacementVO, qrImageSize) + margins[1];
                
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = getImage();
                PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
                        PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
                PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(newDocument, bufferedImage);
                
                //ADDED CODE HERE TO SCALE THE IMAGE
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
                    Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(rotation), 0, 0);
                    PDRectangle cropBox = pdPage.getCropBox();
                    float tx = (cropBox.getLowerLeftX() + cropBox.getUpperRightX()) / 2;
                    float ty = (cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + cropBox.getUpperRightY()) / 2;

                    Rectangle rectang = cropBox.transform(matrix).getBounds();
                    float scale = Math.min(cropBox.getWidth() / (float)rectang.getWidth(), cropBox.getHeight() / (float)rectang.getHeight());

                    pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty));
                    pageContentStream.transform(matrix);
                    pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
                    pageContentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(-tx, -ty));
                }
                
                pageContentStream.drawImage(image, rectLlx, rectLly, qrImageSize, qrImageSize);
                pageContentStream.close();
            }
        
        newDocument.save(new File(getDestinationFilePath(false)));
        
        newDocument.close();
        pdDocument.close();
```

Please guide me that what causing this image size decreasing or tell me if I have need to change approach for page rotation.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Could you please help me with this. Let me know if any details required.

Comment: I have no idea what this is about. You want to scale the content and you're surprised that the image is scaled?

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr It has worked for me. Actually, there was a little issue with the calculation of image size in my code :)